# Accessing a factory from another submodule in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-factory

There are more questions on this, but i can't seem to find the answer to my specific problem.

I use a lot of submodules in my AngularJS app. Sometimes i want to make use of an existing factory, which was previously created in another submodule.

```
angular.module('app', ['users','login']);

angular.module('users', [])
.factory('UserFactory', function($http) {
    return {
        create: function() {
            return {};
        }
    };
});

angular.module('login', ['users'])
.controller('LoginCtrl', function(UserFactory) {
    UserFactory.create();
});
```

When i refresh my app with this code, it will trigger an Error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.4/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20UserFactory
>   z/

Comment: The error you've pasted is talking about something different - missing `$scopeProvider`, which suggests the error is in a part of code you're not showing.

Comment: The last bit of the error is talking about `UserFactory`. So i think the `$scopeProvider` is passing that error.

Comment: The code you've linked [runs fine](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJbqQa), so as I said, the problem must be elsewhere. Please provide a live jsfiddle/codepen reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Stupid mistake and stupid idea to clean my code before posting here!

In the real code i added `$scope` to the factory.

When i removed `$scope`, everything worked fine...